# How to enumerate nodes/edges in OSM?

Tags: routes, openstreetmap, enumeration, edges

We use OSM fairly naively for routing.    We'd also like to build some
simple street grid geometry metrics.

To do that, we need to be able to enumerate nodes and edges within a bounding box.
Alternately, we could start with a single node or edge (assuming we can project
to a closest candidate from a known point), and recursively enumerate neighbors until we cover our region of interest.

I suspect there's got to be a way to do that, either somewhere in the OSM routing API, or in a layered tool that someone has built.

Ideal:  an API for C#/.Net 4.0 or 4.5, as we're running locally-cached OSM routing data and map tiles.

Can someone offer guidance?

thanks --
   Carl
   cdn atsign coelo period com

Comment: You could use ikvm and graphhopper but there are also other routing engines for C#: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing

Comment: I have trouble understanding your problem, nodes and ways in OSM already have a unique ID. Can you rephrase your question?